# Indexer Re-index goes to suspend in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing

I have 60 million products in my magento 2 store.
I have started `indexer:reindex` so it will struck on `catalog_category_product` it shows processing in this and on schedule status it shows suspended in this what's the issue in this ?

[image]

I have **reset the indexer** for all and for this data also but on again starting it shows suspended .

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: process is running will update you if anything comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following stuff:

First You need to change the mode of indexing to `Update on Save` by using this command

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
```

After that you need to reset the indexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

After that truncate `_cl` tables related to your issue occuring indexing

After that reindex the indexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Finally you need to change the mode of indexing to `Update by Schedule`

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
```

I hope it may help you

Comment: Thanks for your response i have 41 tables related to _cl ending which onw i have to truncate or all of them.
Or i have to just truncate catalog_category_product_cl this table.

Will you please help me with this .

Comment: just truncate `catalog_category_product_cl`

Comment: One more question firstly i have to run indexer:reindex then make it to Update by Schedule or make it Update by Schedule then reindex it.
Because i have read that if my product is more then i have to make it update on Schedule.
will you please clear this.

Comment: No, follow the instruction. First **update on save**, then **rest**, then **truncate**, then reindex, then last make **update on schedule** on your requried indexes

Comment: i have follow your instruction and run indexer:reindex it is running from 6 hr and it is still showing processing on catalog_category_product. As, i have 60 million product so do you have any idea about what's the time to get it completed or if any occurs where would i look into.

Comment: 600 million is huge. I have no idea how much time will it take

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117657/discussion-between-prits-and-shoaib-munir).